# How to avoid overwriting when appending updated matrices to a list?

Tags: python, list, matrix, variable-assignment

I'll try to explain this as simply as possible...
The following code is taken from within a function I have defined.
I'm updating the value `R` for every step, which I know works fine. `R` is a matrix and I need to add every updated matrix to the list `R_list_eq`. When I print the list, I do get a list of matrices, but they're all the same, so I guess the code is overwriting somewhere.

```
R_list_eq = []

R, V, F, box_width = md.initialize_particles(n_atoms, temperature, rho, eps)

for n in range(20000):
    R += dt * V + 0.5 * dt**2 * F
    if n > 10000:
        R_list_eq.append(R)
```

Comment: You need to append a copy, i.e. `R_list_eq.append(R.copy())`. Otherwise all entries refer to the same (updated) object.

Comment: Try with `R = R +` instead of `R +=`. Some objects are mutated by `+=`

Comment: when do you want R reset to the first value of tuple return by *initialize_particles* ?

Comment: You're appending multiple references to whatever the last object the name `R` was assigned to at the end of the `for` loop. Try appending a ***copy*** of its current value instead. You can use the [`copy`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#module-copy) module to do this or there may be some faster or easier way depending on what exactly the `R` object is (like a dictionary or list — "matrix" is not a native Python type).

Comment: Also see this [article](https://effbot.org/zone/python-objects.htm) regarding objects vs names.

Answer (score 0):

I have edit you if statment `if n > 10000 and R not in R_list_eq:`, This will avoid overwriting.

```
R_list_eq = []

R, V, F, box_width = md.initialize_particles(n_atoms, temperature, rho, eps)

for n in range(20000):
    R += dt * V + 0.5 * dt**2 * F
    if n > 10000 and R not in R_list_eq:
        R_list_eq.append(R)
```